# global costmap is rotated compared to the map

Tags: ros, navigation, amcl, 2dcostmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there.
I use navigation stack to perform autonomous navigation in known map.
I got help from this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup but, as you can see in the picture below, global costmap is rotated compared to the map. The degrees are not fixed, other times it's 90 degrees, other times 180, or ~40 compared to the map.
Everything else (goal pose, local path, global path) is working right according to generated costmaps.
Any thoughts?

[image description http://s31.postimg.org/hmnnwrv23/Screenshot_from_2016_04_21_18_12_48.png](http://s31.postimg.org/hmnnwrv23/Screenshot_from_2016_04_21_18_12_48.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232509/global-costmap-is-rotated-compared-to-the-map/) by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-21**:
Out of curiosity, which simulator is this on the right screen?

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2016-04-22**:
V-REP. It's easy to use and has a ROS wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just figured out I should push the button "2D Pose Estimate" in RViz.
But how can we perform SLAM ("Synchronous" Localization and Mapping) if we should give the initial position of the robot in the room?

---

Originally posted by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) with karma: 20 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-04-21**:
You should add this as an edit to your original question or make a new question if you want to get answers. Right now it appears that you have solved it since you start your answer with `I just figured out`.